# Is it possible to set default border radius in Theme in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am learning `Theme` and `ThemeData` for Flutter.
I can comfortable deal with colors, however I am missing a global `BorderRadius` setting.

How to make (via `ThemeData`) that all widgets will have `BorderRadius` 0 by default (sharp corners)?

Comment: you can create a wrapper widget with borderRadius

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is possible. You can change the `borderRadius` for every button type. To do so, add the following lines to your `ThemeData`:

```
textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    ),
  ),
),
```

You can see that all of your `TextButtons` should now have a `borderRadius` of 8. This works for all other buttons accordingly.

Comment: So basically I need to set separately for all buttons, cardTheme, input themes, etc.? There is no single "default radius" ?

Comment: @MaciejPszczolinski sadly not, you could however define a variable to use in all of your different themes. That would make it somewhat like what you want.